# About sphere with equatorial opposite identification

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I need some help about the definition of projective space.
I read on the wiki that the $S^n\simeq \mathbb{R}P^n$ and while i understood how to get $S^n$ from the projetive space I struggle with the other way around.
To be more precise I do not understand how the equatorial opposite identification (let's call that $\sim$) create 2 equal half-sphere. In $S^1$ I think is pretty clear, since $S^1/\sim\simeq S^1/S^0$ and that is the figure-8.
But if we take $S^2$ as an example I really struggle to understand how those two opposite half-sphere could be equal.

Edit (to be more clear):
Let's take the relation $\sim$ where $x\sim -x$ on the equator of my sphere $S^2$. I need to show that $S^2/\sim\simeq \mathbb{R}P^2$.
The first step to show that usally is to consider just one half sphere with the equator properly identified.
In all the books and notes I have they just say that since the upper and the lower half are equal you can consider just one of the two. The point where I'm struggling the most is why those two half are equal.

Comment: Pls try to elaborate more your question: define precisely your equivalence and ask a precise question. (My feeling right now is that you don't know exactly what you want to ask, you just seem a little confused in understanding projective spaces)

Comment: @user126154 done. 
I think I understood how the projective plane works. Probably my problems are more about some other basic things I thought I understood during my firsts years in uni.
Sadly I know that I have some huge deficits in geometry fundamental concepts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have misread. Having a homeomorphism $\Bbb S^n \cong \Bbb RP^n$ or even a homotopy equivalence $\Bbb S^n \cong \Bbb RP^n$ breaks down from $n=2$ onwards: they have different singular homology say, so they must be distinct. (If you don’t know about homology yet this is not really a problem. My point is that one can prove that what you want to prove is impossible to hold true)

In the case $n=1$ one indeed has a homeomorphism $\Bbb S^1 \cong \Bbb RP^1$. One always has a **quotient map** $\Bbb S^n \rightarrow \Bbb S^n/\pm 1 =: \Bbb RP^n$, which one often takes as the definition of $\Bbb RP^n$. In the case $n=1$ we note that we can represent $\Bbb S^1/\pm 1$ by $[0,\pi]/\{0,\pi\}$, which itself is homeomorphic to $\Bbb S^1$.

Comment: How can I show that they have different singular homology?
bacause that's exactly what brought me to this path

Comment: The easiest way I know of is using the fact that on CW-complexes singular and cellular homology coincidence. The cellular homology of $\Bbb S^n$ is given by $\Bbb Z$ in degrees 0 and $n$ and is 0 otherwise. The CW-structure of $\Bbb RP^n$ is a bit more involved and is given by gluing disks along antipodal maps for one $k\leq n$ at a time (you may want to look this up). This will give alternatingly homology $\Bbb Z, \Bbb Z_2, \Bbb Z, ...$ up to degree $n$ and 0 otherwise.